# Receive JSON resposte in Android with unknow multiple names and set it on a spinner

Tags: php, android, json, spinner

My android app need's to receive a list of unknow people (they have to registrate on web) and have to set that list on a spinner.

Can you give me an example of the json array I have to send from the php web and how to catch it with android?

Comment: there's no such thing as a json array. there's a json STRING, which may contain the definition of an array. if it helps, in a javascript assignment, e.g. `var x = "string"`, json is the basically part occupied by `"string"`. you don't work with json, you just use json to get data from one system toanother. you always decode json back to a native structure, at work with native data types.

Answer (score 1):

A possible json array:

[ "name1", "name2", "name3" ]

Parsing you do in help of Android's JSON lib:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Have fun!